# Where is the Treasure located in the Cave area of the Terran Ruins (1-5)?

Tags: chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters

I cannot find it. Things I have tried include (all attempts were after enemies were cleared):

- Running around the stone column and hitting it
- Breaking all the barrels and torches
- Breaking all the barrels then breaking all the torches with Icicle Edge
- Breaking all the torches with the Hammerball
- Running around the edges of the map trying to find some piece of wall to hit to trigger it

I give up. I'm really hoping that this isn't a case of just having to pixel hunt to get the exact right area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The objective of this room is that you must defeat a powerful foe. But not just defeat it, you must defeat it first! As such, if you try to look after clearing the room out, you'll never get it. Quite fiendish.

I speak of none other than the very fast skeleton that is at the exit. You need to go over to it and kill it without killing any of the other enemies in the room. A pretty easy task, honestly, they won't harass you if you just run. As a skeleton, remember that you can kill harm it with spells, so either bring some gems with you from a previous room. Or, you can break the torches or the grass in that area fairly safely to harvest some gems.

The prize you claim is...

> Speedboots! They can be worn to increase your moving speed, and count as a pair of shoes (you can only wear 2 at a time). They're... really, they're as awesome as they sound and may easily find their way into a very common slot in your equipment.